# unroll a tuple for print

Tags: python, tuples, string-formatting

I want to append the values of a `tuple` to a string. However I don't get it to work with slices...

Actually I only want the values as in `out[18]` below, and not the brackets, spaces, and commas that one gets with `'{0}'.format(thetuple)`.

Any ideas?

```
In [16]: cg = (3,1)

In [17]: cg[0:2]
Out[17]: (3, 1)

In [18]: 'cg{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format(cg)
Out[18]: 'cg31'

In [19]: 'cg{0[0:2]}'.format(cg)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-a450c51616c2> in <module>()
----> 1 'cg{0[0:2]}'.format(cg)

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
>>> st = ''.join(str(s) for s in cg)
>>> st
'31'
```

You iterate over the tuple and use `.join()` on the empty string.  Be sure to cast each element in the `tuple` as a `str` while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it somehow like this:

```
string = ''
for i in (3,1):
    string+=(str(i))
print string
```

Output is 31 :)